# Making parallel requests to the network using async and processing them in the supervisorScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a little problem with doing asynchronous work. Conventionally, I need to somehow process 2 **.async** calls and get their value (using **await()** ). Didn't quite understand how to do it with **SupervisorScope**.

Function:

```
fun getInfo() { 
    supervisorScope {
      val firstInfo = async { ... }
      val secondInfo = async { ... }

      val first = try {
          firstInfo.await()
      } catch(ex: Exception) {
        
      }

      val second = try {
          secondInfo.await()
      } catch(ex: Exception) {
        
      }
    }

    // Here you need to get the values ​​​​from .await() and write them to a variable
    state.copy (
       currentFirst = first,
       currentSecond = second,
    )
}
```

The problem is also that exceptions can occur at the place where await is called. How can these exceptions be handled? Thank you in advance!

UPD: The function should not return anything, it should just take the values ​​from .await(), handle exceptions and assign values ​​to variables as well

Comment: What is your expected behavior in the case of an exception?

Comment: @broot, when receiving exceptions - for good, you need to tell state that an error has occurred (for example: state.copy( error = "error! try again" ). Well, for the function to end, since the user needs to restart it

Comment: @Tenfour04 state in this case refers to MVI, i.e. we update the state and notify the UI about it

Comment: @Tenfour04 What do you mean my answer doesn't answer the questions? Let's say state is a sealed class, a task for my pet project

Comment: Definition of the class== the source code. Trying to figure out if it's a class that can wrap errors. I asked if it was an assignment to determine if you can modify this class or if you need to do this in a specific way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just misunderstood you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `supervisorScope` to wrap the whole function.

```
suspend fun getInfo() = supervisorScope {
    val firstInfo = async { ... }
    val secondInfo = async { ... }

    val first = try {
        firstInfo.await()
    } catch(ex: Exception) {
        state = state.copy(error = ex)
        return@supervisorScope
    }

    val second = try {
        secondInfo.await()
    } catch(ex: Exception) {
        state = state.copy(error = ex)
        return@supervisorScope
    }

    state = state.copy (
       currentFirst = first,
       currentSecond = second,
    )
}
```

or, collapsing the logic to something simpler:

```
suspend fun getInfo() = supervisorScope {
    val firstInfo = async { ... }
    val secondInfo = async { ... }

    state = try {
        state.copy (
           currentFirst = firstInfo.await(),
           currentSecond = secondInfo.await(),
        )
    } catch(ex: Exception) {
        state.copy(error = ex)
    }
}
```

If you don't need to wait for the results and want to be able to call this function from outside coroutines, you would start a coroutine in this function.

```
fun getInfo() {
    someCoroutineScope.launch { // probably viewModelScope if this is in ViewModel
        supervisorScope {
            // same code as above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what you need, the function should not return anything. It should be a state change.

Comment: I will update the question